# How to execute a JavaScript function from MVC Razor code for an included JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In a JavaScript block in a MVC4 Razor view, I can do:

```
function loginError() {
    $('#loginFailed').fadeIn();
}

@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // login failed
    @:loginError();
}
```

However, if `loginError()` is contained in an external JS file, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loginError is not defined

How can I execute JS functions from .Net code in a Razor view for imported JS files?

Comment: as long as the javascript file is referenced before you attempt the call everything should work fine

Comment: Any update? I am facing the same issue. here is my code     <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetconfigColCount() {
            return 3;
        }    
    </script>
    
    </head>
@{
        ViewBag.colCount =  @:GetconfigColCount();
}   It gives ; missing error, if i removed the @{ ... } then error goes. I put the @{..} inside the head , and inside the script but issue still there. I like to call it before body tag  part as the count will effect the dynamic table formation in the body before ready function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you put your `<script />` tag to import the JS file before your call to the `loginError();` function. You might want to put it in your HTML's `<head>`.